# Android ServerSocket only accepting localhost connections

Tags: android, sockets

I have a server application running on my Android phone. I successfully transfer packets back and forth between a c++ application running on my PC and the Android phone connected to the PC running the application via USB.

However, I can't connect to the socket when the c++ application is running on a different PC than the one where the phone is connected. Using netstat I can see that the socket is bound to the right port, but on the local address 127.0.0.1. This is why my setup works when the application and the phone are on the same computer: 127.0.0.1 is the localhost address.

How can I open the socket to make it available to my other computer? I tried forcing the ServerSocket to bind to InetAddress 0.0.0.0 and InetAddress null as was suggested elsewhere, but the socket is still bound to the address 127.0.0.1. I also added the INTERNET permission to my android manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Please note that I created a separate c++ server on the remote PC where the phone is connected. If I open a socket using this server I can see that the socket is bound to the address 0.0.0.0 and I can successfully connect to it. This is why I'm pretty sure that the problem is linked to the socket being bound to the address 127.0.0.1 when opening it from the phone app.

Comment: Just open the serversocket specifying a port only. Don't fiddle around with ip adresses.

Comment: Are you using 127.0.0.1 as server ip address for the client?

Comment: greenapps, that's what I was doing at first. Since it would keep binding the port to 127.0.0.1 I tried to force it to 0.0.0.0 by specifying the ip address. Also, I was using 127.0.0.1 for the client when the phone was connected on the PC running the c++ application. Now I have to use the real ip of the server since the application is running on a separate computer.

Comment: A client cannot use 0.0.0.0 to connect to a server. The client used that 127.0.0.1 when the socketserver was on the first pc. Which address does the client use if the socket server is on the second pc?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is the local address where the socket is bound (sockets have an address and a port). It means the socket can accept connections from "anyone". On the contrary, a socket bound to the local address 127.0.0.1 will only accept connections from the local host. Since the PC was on the same network as the phone in the first scenario, the PC client could connect to the socket. In the second scenario I use the IP address of the computer where the phone is plugged in, but the socket opened by the phone is bound to the address 127.0.0.1, which means it will not accept the connection from the PC.

Comment: `In the second scenario I use the IP address of the computer where the phone is plugged in,`. That is wrong. The android client should use the ip addres of the second computer(where the server socket runs). `but the socket opened by the phone is bound to the address127.0.0.1,` ??? The phone tries to connect only. `it will not accept the connection from the PC.`. ??? The app on your phone is not accepting connections as it is a client. The serversocket on your second pc will by default accept connections from all kind of ip adresses.

Comment: @greenapps: You need to gets the facts straight. The Android app is the server and the C++ app is the client. This is clearly stated in the question: "I have a server application running on my Android phone." The Android app is binding its `ServerSocket` to 127.0.0.1 and thus is not accepting a connection from the client unless the client is run on the same PC that the Android phone is connected to via USB.

Comment: @AndrewMpy: please show your actual code that is setting up both sides of the connection.  The `ServerSocket` should not be binding to 127.0.0.1 unless you are telling it to - unless maybe Android itself is forcing it to 127.0.0.1 when connected via USB.  Try connecting the phone to your LAN using WiFi instead and see if your client can then connect to the phone. Also, do you have USB Debugging enabled on the phone?  Are you using any Android emulators at the same time the connection is failing?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I misread all. Sorry.

Comment: `Please note that I created a separate c++ server on the remote PC where the phone is connected. If I open a socket using this server I can see..` if you ask why...  c++ was the server in my mind...